# Reusable code that I can store in the function.php and apply to other templates as need. Dry Code

Tags: php, customization

I am trying to apply reusable code to some single-posttype template and I was wonder if I can store the code somehow in the function.php and include it where i want to.

Here is the code

```
 if (!empty( get_field('social_title') )):
    $socialTitle = get_field('social_title');
    $socialContent = get_field('social_content');
    $link = get_field('social_link');
    $cleanString = strip_tags($socialContent);
    $cleanTitle = strip_tags($socialTitle);
else:
    $cleanTitle = strip_tags($postobj->post_title );
    $cleanSocialContent = strip_tags(get_field('content'));
    $shortString = substr ($cleanSocialContent, 0, 137);
    $stringsize = strlen($shortString);
    if ($stringsize > 136):
        $cleanString = $shortString . "...";
    else:
        $cleanString = $shortString;
    endif;
endif;
```

Here is how its being used in a template

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    /** Post object */
    $postobj = get_post();
    /** Whats the previous post */
    $previous_post = get_previous_post();
    /** whats the next post  */
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    /** Whats the categories  */
    $cats = get_the_category();
    /** grab first categorie  */
    $cat_name = $cats[0]->name;

    /** Post Content in its raw form, so html tags are showing. The $cleanstring has been stripped of the html tags  */
    /** check if Social Content available if not grab the first 100 

    charactors and add a ... to the end  */
        if (!empty( get_field('social_title') )):
    $socialTitle = get_field('social_title');
    $socialContent = get_field('social_content');
    $link = get_field('social_link');
    $cleanString = strip_tags($socialContent);
    $cleanTitle = strip_tags($socialTitle);
else:
    $cleanTitle = strip_tags($postobj->post_title );
    $cleanSocialContent = strip_tags(get_field('content'));
    $shortString = substr ($cleanSocialContent, 0, 137);
    $stringsize = strlen($shortString);
    if ($stringsize > 136):
        $cleanString = $shortString . "...";
    else:
        $cleanString = $shortString;
    endif;
endif;
     ?>
        <?php get_template_part('slider-yellow'); ?>
        <div id="single-article">
            <article class="row">
                <div id="social-icon-cont" class="medium-2 columns">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="social-link facebook-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="popup" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=SEIU&text=<?php echo $cleanString ?>" target="_blank">
                                <span class="social-link twitter-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="mailto:?&subject=<?php echo $cleanTitle ?>&body=<?php echo $cleanString ?>">
                                <span class="social-link share-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Where is `$tags` coming from

Comment: Also, do you need raw post content, if so use the `post_content` property of the post object or `get_the_content()`

Comment: $tags is coming from function.php since I use it in a lot of places. I just wanna do something like get_template_part, but I think thats not grabbing my vars. :(  I just want some sort of placeholder, so I can change the code in one place and not have to change it in all of the templates.

Comment: You should post the code to `$tags`. In your question it is an undefined variable. The contents of `$tags` is really important in order to give a specific answer.

Comment: I removed the $tags completely and used strip_tags function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start, if you need to pass variables between template parts, you have to check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/184235/31545). There are exceptional answers (specially from @kaiser and @gmazzap) on how to achieve this, specially without having to use globals ;-)

There are a ton of stuff that you would need to do first as we really need to avoid bugs and fatal errors due ACF beign deactivated or due to something that does not exist.

### A FEW NOTES

- The following code is untested and may contain bugs. Be sure to test this locally first. Also note that the code requires at least PHP 5.4
- I have never worked with ACF, I have quickly read the relevant documentation and implemented my understanding of the docs in my code
- Use, abuse and modify the code as needed. The code is very static, but you can make it dynamic. As I do not know exaactly how you would want to use it, it might be an idea to extend this to incorporate your links and feed into the function itself, but this you need to do yourself.
- I have commented the code for easy following and understanding

### THE CODE

```
/** Function to return either the title or content from an ACF field choice
 *
 * @param (string) $to_return Value are 'title' or 'content'
 * @return (string) $output
 */
function get_single_variable( $to_return = '' ) 
{
    /**
     * First get our current post object. This section is something I'm experimenting 
     * with get a reliable way to pass the current post object as $post is not reliable.
     * NOTE: query_posts will break get_queried_object(), this is one reason you should
     * never ever use query_posts
     */
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $current_post = get_queried_object();
    } else {
        $current_post = get_post();
    }

    // Make sure we have a valid vale for $to_return, if not return an empty string
    if (    'title'   !== $to_return
         && 'content' !== $to_return
    )
        return '';


    // Make sure ACF is activated and that get_fields are available. If not, bail out and return an empty strin
    if ( !function_exists( 'get_fields' ) )
        return '';

    // Now that we now get_fields exists and we will not recieve fatal errors, lets safely continue

    // We will now get all the fields belonging to the post at once
    $fields = get_fields( $current_post->ID );
    // ?><pre><?php var_dump( $fields ); ?></pre><?php // For debugging purposes, just uncomment it to dump the value of $fields

    //Set our variables to avoid bugs like undefined variables
    $cleaned_title   = '';
    $cleaned_content = '';

    // Setup our conditional statements
    $social_title = $fields['social_title'];
    if ( !empty( $social_title ) ) {
        // Use wp_strip_all_tags to use native functions (which is filterable), stip_tags are still valid though
        $cleaned_title   = wp_strip_all_tags( $fields['social_title']   );
        $cleaned_content = wp_strip_all_tags( $fields['social_content'] );
    } else { 
        $cleaned_title = wp_strip_all_tags( $current_post->post_title );

        // Get our content from another field now
        $cleaned_social_content = wp_strip_all_tags( $fields['content'] );
        // Use mb_substr() and mb_strlen() which is multibyte safe
        if ( 136 < mb_strlen( $cleaned_social_content ) ) {
            $excerpt_more    = __( '&hellip;' );
            $cleaned_content =  mb_substr( $cleaned_social_content, 0, 137 ) . $excerpt_more;
        } else {
            $cleaned_content = $cleaned_social_content;
        }
    }

    if ( 'title' === $to_return ) {
        return $cleaned_title;
    } else { 
        return $cleaned_content;
    }
}
```

You can now use it anywhere to display the title or content as follow

```
echo get_single_variable( 'title' );
```

or

```
echo get_single_variable( 'content' );
```