# How to fix a “globals” issue to avoid a rejected theme?

Tags: code, globals

I submit a WordPress theme for Themeforest and one of the reasons for rejection was as follows:

> Globals should always be within a function or a class and should be used restrictively & only if theme really needs to. It's highly recommended not to use them at all just to keep things out of the global namespace, they're poor coding practice.

Im using [Smof Option Framework](https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework) for theme options and here is a sample code from one of my theme files:

```
global $smof_data;
$td_header_manager_wide = $smof_data['td_header_blocks']['enabled'];

if ( $td_header_manager_wide ) {

        foreach ( $td_header_manager_wide as $key=>$value ) {

            switch( $key ) {

                case 'block_main_menu_wide': // wide menu
                echo '<div id="td-sticky" class="wide-menu ' . $td_sticky . '">';
                echo '<div id="wide-menu">';
                include( get_template_directory() . '/parts/menu-header-logo.php');
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                break;
  }
}
```

It seems that **global $smof_data**; should be within a function but I'm really lost here how to accomplish this task to avoid include global $smof_data; in all of my theme files where I need it.

Update code using @jgraup method:

```
function matilda_customize_styles() {

    $css = '<style type="text/css" media="screen">';
    if ( ! empty( SMOFData::get( 'td_body_font_family' ) ) 
        && SMOFData::get( 'td_body_font_family' ) != 'none' ) 
    {
        $css .= 'body{font-family:' . esc_html( SMOFData::get( 'td_body_font_family' ) ) . ';}';
    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with framework that holds values in a global variable then there isn't much you can do about it. Here is an example of wrapping the variable in a static getter.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'SMOFData' ) ):

    class SMOFData {

        static public function is( $key, $compare ) {
            $value = static::get( $key );
            return $value === $compare;
        }

        static public function not( $key, $compare ) {
            $value = static::get( $key );
            return $value !== $compare;
        }

        static public function has( $key ) {
            $value = static::get( $key );
            return ! empty( $value );
        }

        static public function get( $key ) {

            global $smof_data;

            if ( ! isset( $smof_data ) ) {
                return null;
            }

            return isset( $smof_data[ $key ] ) ? $smof_data[ $key ] : null;
        }

    }

endif; // SMOFData
```

To access the data just use

```
echo SMOFData::get('td_header_blocks')['enabled'];

function matilda_customize_styles() { 
    $css = '<style type="text/css" media="screen">';
    $td_body_font_family = SMOFData::get( 'td_body_font_family' ); 
    if ( ! empty( $td_body_font_family ) && $td_body_font_family != 'none' ) {
        $css .= 'body{font-family:' . esc_html( $td_body_font_family ) . ';}';
    } 
}

function matilda_customize_styles() { 
    $css = '<style type="text/css" media="screen">';
    if ( SMOFData::has( 'td_body_font_family' ) && SMOFData::not( 'td_body_font_family', 'none' ) ) {
            $css .= 'body{font-family:' . esc_html( SMOFData::get( 'td_body_font_family' ) ) . ';}';
    }
}
```

---

If you just want you're own globals you can wrap that in a class as well.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'ThemeData' ) ):

    class ThemeData {
        private static $_values = array ();

        static public function get( $key ) {
            return isset( static::$_values[ $key ] ) ? static::$_values[ $key ] : null;
        }

        static public function set( $key, $value ) {
            static::$_values[ $key ] = $value;
            return $value;
        }
    }
endif; // ThemeData


// setter
ThemeData::set('foo', 'bar');

// getter
echo ThemeData::get('foo');
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method works great in my sample code above but I really don't know how to use the class in the following code: `if( !empty( $smof_data['td_body_font_family'] ) and $smof_data['td_body_font_family'] != 'none' ) {
 $css .= 'body{font-family:'. esc_html( $smof_data['td_body_font_family']) .';}';
 }`Can you give me a little more help with this?

Comment: Thanks. I guess your code is write but since most of my code where I use `$smof_data['key']` are within a function, using `SMOFData::get( 'key' )` I get a fatal error: `Can't use function return value in write context` Any clues?

Comment: The error occurs on line `if ( ! empty( SMOFData::get( 'td_body_font_family' ) )` but your update sample seems to work now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, they are. Best!

Comment: Just a weird issue: on my xampp local server all things works fine but on a live server I get an error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' The line which its mocking about is this one:`$td_header_layout = SMOFData::get('td_header_blocks')['enabled'];` Any suggestion? May be the PHP version? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just pull the value into a variable before you try to access the 'enabled'. Or see what happens when you wrap the first call with ( class::method() )[key]

Comment: Thanks for your readiness!  So how should look this line in order to work? `$td_header_layout = SMOFData::get('td_header_blocks')['enabled'];`

Comment: $td = (SMOFData::get(  'td_header_blocks' ))['enabled']; or $td = SMOFData::get(  'td_header_blocks' ); $td_header = $td['enabled'];

Comment: This method seems to work : `$td = SMOFData::get( 'td_header_blocks' ); $td_header = $td['enabled']; ` Thank you very much!

Comment: My current PHP version: 5.3.28. It seems that is a php 5.3 version issue: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358973/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-with-php-5-3)

Answer (score 3):

First, I must congratulate the reply from Themeforest, that really deserves a beer. Globals are evil and one should never create globals and dirty the global space anymore that it already is. WordPress has made a huge mess of this already. Don't add to this mess.

One of the easiest ways to get pass the global issue is to create a function which you can use anywhere where you would need it. Here is a sample

```
function this_is_my_global()
{
    return $my_global_var = 'This is my global value';
}
```

You can then simply call `this_is_my_global();` where you need it.

This is just something very basic. I would recommend that you read @kaiser and @gmazzap answers to the following question

- [Best way of passing PHP variable between partials?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/184235/31545)

That should give a more complex, reliable means to pass variables between templates

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. I'm still a litle confused. Can you update your answer according to my concrete example using `$smof_data` in your sample code? Thanks!

Comment: I do not know your framework, so I do not know what `$smof_data` holds or where it is defined